# Tensorflow not training with detection boundary boxes

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm using model_main_tf2.py to try and train a detection model. When I invoke it using `python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8 --pipeline_config_path=ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8\pipeline.config`, training starts, but it doesn't train with any detection or boundary boxes. I specify detection in the pipeline, which you can see here;

```
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 320
        width: 320
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          random_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.009999999776482582
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      use_depthwise: true
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        additional_layer_depth: 128
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 128
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
        share_prediction_tower: true
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 10
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.07999999821186066
          total_steps: 10000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.026666000485420227
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 10000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RedGoal_TrackerCSRT_1.000000/label.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RedGoal_TrackerCSRT_1.000000/train-00.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RedGoal_TrackerCSRT_1.000000/label.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/RedGoal_TrackerCSRT_1.000000/eval-00.record"
  }
}
```

and I get these warnings when I start

```
W0117 12:13:12.446329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._groundtruth_lists
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor
W0117 12:13:12.448330 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._batched_prediction_tensor_names
W0117 12:13:12.452328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._batched_prediction_tensor_names
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head
W0117 12:13:12.453329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads
W0117 12:13:12.454330 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._sorted_head_names
W0117 12:13:12.456328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._sorted_head_names
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers
W0117 12:13:12.457328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads
W0117 12:13:12.458329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers
W0117 12:13:12.459329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers
W0117 12:13:12.461329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background
W0117 12:13:12.462329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.0
W0117 12:13:12.463328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.1
W0117 12:13:12.465329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.2
W0117 12:13:12.468328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.3
W0117 12:13:12.470329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.4
W0117 12:13:12.471328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._additional_projection_layers.4
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings
W0117 12:13:12.472329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background
W0117 12:13:12.473329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower
W0117 12:13:12.474330 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower
W0117 12:13:12.475329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0
W0117 12:13:12.477328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background._class_predictor_layers
W0117 12:13:12.479329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background._class_predictor_layers
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0
W0117 12:13:12.481329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1
W0117 12:13:12.481329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2
W0117 12:13:12.481329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3
W0117 12:13:12.482329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4
W0117 12:13:12.482329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.0
W0117 12:13:12.483329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.1
W0117 12:13:12.483329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.2
W0117 12:13:12.484329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.3
W0117 12:13:12.484329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4
W0117 12:13:12.485329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.class_predictions_with_background.4
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.0
W0117 12:13:12.485329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.1
W0117 12:13:12.486329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.2
W0117 12:13:12.486329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.3
W0117 12:13:12.487328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.PredictionTower.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.0
W0117 12:13:12.488329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.1
W0117 12:13:12.488329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.2
W0117 12:13:12.489328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.3
W0117 12:13:12.489328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._head_scope_conv_layers.ClassPredictionTower.3
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0.depthwise_kernel
W0117 12:13:12.490329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0.depthwise_kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0.pointwise_kernel
W0117 12:13:12.490329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0.pointwise_kernel
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0.bias
W0117 12:13:12.491329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._box_prediction_head._box_encoder_layers.0.bias
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background._class_predictor_layers.0
W0117 12:13:12.491329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._prediction_heads.class_predictions_with_background._class_predictor_layers.0
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.1
W0117 12:13:12.492329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.2
W0117 12:13:12.492329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.4
W0117 12:13:12.492329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.4
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.5
W0117 12:13:12.493329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.5
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.7
W0117 12:13:12.493329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.7
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.8
W0117 12:13:12.494328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.8
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.10
W0117 12:13:12.494328 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.10
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.11
W0117 12:13:12.495329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.0.11
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1.1
W0117 12:13:12.496329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1.1
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1.2
W0117 12:13:12.496329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1.2
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1.4
W0117 12:13:12.497329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.1.4
W0117 12:13:12.592329 11792 util.py:161] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W0117 12:13:12.592329 11792 util.py:169] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
...
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:605: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
W0117 12:13:17.169330 11884 deprecation.py:537] From C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:605: calling map_fn_v2 (from tensorflow.python.ops.map_fn) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use fn_output_signature instead
```

(Limited for size)

Has anyone encountered this before? I'm using Python 3.6 and tensorflow-gpu 2.4.0.